# javascript function with parameter called without parameter?

Tags: javascript

I was checking out an example of javascript code from w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

If function showPosition by definition has a parameter called position: 
`function showPosition(position) {... }`

why is it possible to call it with no parameters:
    `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);`

Example is functional, just trying to understand it

In fact am surprised showPosition has a param at all. Would you change that?

Comment: You are not calling `showPosition`, you are just passing the function reference to `getCurrentPosition` which will call the function with the parameter once the position data is obtained

Comment: The function reference is being passed in as an argument, this is because in JS functions are first class objects. This kind of use is called a **callback**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not calling the function, it's passing the function as an argument to another function. `getCurrentPosition` uses the argument as a callback, and it will later call the function with the appropriate argument.

A function call always has parentheses after the function name, e.g. `showPosition(something)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is `arguments` array-like object in JS which allows to skip actual parameters at all and use `arguments[0]` for `position` in your case.

Comment: That's not relevant to the question.